# How to count strings separated by a semicolon

Tags: r, string, count

My data looks like below:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(7L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("", "cell and biogenesis;transport", 
"differentiation;metabolic process;regulation;stimulus", "MAPK cascade;cell and biogenesis", 
"MAPK cascade;cell and biogenesis;transport", "metabolic process;regulation;stimulus;transport", 
"mRNA;stimulus;transport", "targeting"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I want to count how many similar strings are there but also have a track from which row they come from. Each string is separated by a `;` but they belong to the row that they are in there.

I want to have the output like this:

```
String                           Count        position 
mRNA                                 1        1
stimulus                             3        1,6,11
transport                            4        1,5,9,11
MAPK cascade                         2        2,5
cell and biogenesis                  3        2,5,9
targeting                            2        3,4
regulation of mRNA stability         1        1
regulation                           2        6,11
differentiation                      1        6,11
metabolic process                    2        6,11
```

The count shows how many times each of the string (the string are separated by a semicolon) is repeated in the entire data.
Second column shows where they were, for example mRNA was only in the first row so it is 1. stimulus was in three rows 1 and 6 and 11

Some rows are blank and they are also count as rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code below we do the following:

1. Add the row numbers as a column.
2. Use `strplit` to split each string into its components and store the result in a column called `string`.
3. `strsplit` returns a list. We use `unnest` to stack the list components to create a "long" data frame, giving us a "tidy" data frame that's ready to summarize.
4. Group by `string` and return a new data frame that counts the frequency of each string and gives the original row number in which each instance of the string originally appeared.

---

```
library(tidyverse)

df$V1 = as.character(df$V1)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(string = strsplit(V1, ";")) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  group_by(string) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            rows = paste(rowname, collapse=","))
```

> ```
>                string count     rows
> 1 cell and biogenesis     3    2,5,9
> 2     differentiation     1        6
> 3        MAPK cascade     2      2,5
> 4   metabolic process     2     6,11
> 5                mRNA     1        1
> 6          regulation     2     6,11
> 7            stimulus     3   1,6,11
> 8           targeting     2      3,4
> 9           transport     4 1,5,9,11
> ```

If you plan to do further processing on the row numbers, you might want to keep them as numeric values, rather than as a string of pasted values. In that case, you could do this:

```
df.new = df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("rows") %>% 
  mutate(string = strsplit(V1, ";")) %>% 
  select(-V1) %>%
  unnest
```

This will give you a long data frame with one row for each combination of `string` and `rows`.

Answer (score 3):

A base R approach:

```
# convert 'V1' to a character vector (only necessary of it isn't already)
df$V1 <- as.character(df$V1)

# get the unique strings
strng <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df$V1,';')))

# create a list with the rows for each unique string
lst <- lapply(strng, function(x) grep(x, df$V1, fixed = TRUE))

# get the counts for each string
count <- lengths(lst)

# collpase the list string positions into a string with the rownumbers for each string
pos <- sapply(lst, toString)

# put everything together in one dataframe
d <- data.frame(strng, count, pos)
```

You can shorten this approach to:

```
d <- data.frame(strng = unique(unlist(strsplit(df$V1,';'))))
lst <- lapply(d$strng, function(x) grep(x, df$V1, fixed = TRUE))
transform(d, count = lengths(lst), pos = sapply(lst, toString))
```

The result:

```
> d
                strng count         pos
1                mRNA     1           1
2            stimulus     3    1, 6, 11
3           transport     4 1, 5, 9, 11
4        MAPK cascade     2        2, 5
5 cell and biogenesis     3     2, 5, 9
6           targeting     2        3, 4
7     differentiation     1           6
8   metabolic process     2       6, 11
9          regulation     2       6, 11
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible `data.table` solution for completeness

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(.I, unlist(tstrsplit(V1, ";", fixed = TRUE)))
          ][!is.na(V2), .(count = .N, pos = toString(sort(I))), 
            by = .(String = V2)]
#                 String count         pos
# 1:                mRNA     1           1
# 2:        MAPK cascade     2        2, 5
# 3:           targeting     2        3, 4
# 4:     differentiation     1           6
# 5: cell and biogenesis     3     2, 5, 9
# 6:   metabolic process     2       6, 11
# 7:            stimulus     3    1, 6, 11
# 8:           transport     4 1, 5, 9, 11
# 9:          regulation     2       6, 11
```

This is basically splits `V1` column by `;` while converting to a long format while simultaneously binding it with the row index (`.I`). Afterwards it's just a simple aggregation on row count (`.N`) and binding positions into a single string per `String`.